# Ruby Webdriver. Get all 'data' values from elements in page

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, webdriver

For one html site. I need to get all "data" attribute values for elements with the same class. Those elements have all the same class with different "data" values.

```
div class="logo" data-channel="1"
```

where data-channel="N" is the value I need so i can build a different URL to navigate to it.

I tried a couple of ways to do it without success:
-First I tried to get the "data" values as I always do with href and title attributes:

```
filtros = @driver.find_elements(:class, "logo")
channels_data = []
filtros.each {|f|
    channels_data += [ f[:data] ]
}
channels_data.each {|f|
    puts "data: " + f
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) itv_personalvideo Should test the channels
     Failure/Error: puts "data: " + f
     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of nil into String
     # ./spec/2.2/_web_itv_pc_personalvideo.rb:149:in `+'
     # ./spec/2.2/_web_itv_pc_personalvideo.rb:149:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/2.2/_web_itv_pc_personalvideo.rb:148:in `each'
     # ./spec/2.2/_web_itv_pc_personalvideo.rb:148:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

-Second I tried running javascript code directly as I already have in other test cases:

```
js_element = @driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('.logo')[13].dataset.channel;")
puts js_element
```

But I had another error:

```
Failures:

  1) itv_personalvideo Should test the channels
     Failure/Error: js_element = @driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('.logo')[13].dataset.channel;")
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined
         (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.111)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64)
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:71:in `assert_ok'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:657:in `raw_execute'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:635:in `execute'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:360:in `executeScript'
     # /home/usuario/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:212:in `execute_script'
     # ./spec/2.2/_web_itv_pc_personalvideo.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

That surprised me because in the browser, that Javascript code gave me the number I need:

```
> document.querySelectorAll('.logo')[13].dataset.channel;
"16"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, and book reading, i found the solution:

Here's a list of examples:

```
driver.find_element(:link_text, "element")["href"])
driver.find_element(:link_text, "element")["id"])
driver.find_element(:id, "element").text
driver.find_element(:id, "element").tag_name
driver.find_element(:id, "element").attribute("data-id")
driver.find_element(:id, "element")["style"]
```

Answer (score 0):

to get data of all web elements having same class, below is the script in Java, i hope it will helps you to build in Ruby

```
//collect all the web elements having the class logo
    List<WebElement> data=driver.findElements(By.className("logo"));

    //to get data-channel of each element
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){

        //printing the data-channel value
        System.out.println(data.get(i).getAttribute("data-channel"));
    }
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have some html to test this on, but I'll take a crack at it. First of all, I'm assuming you're only looking for the values of the values of the "data-channel" attribute and not some other "data-*" element. That would require a bit more footwork I think.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
#...
b.divs(:class => "logo").each do |div|
  puts div.attribute_value("data-channel")
end
```

Comment: Sadly we don't use Watir, so im getting the error "undefined method `attribute_value' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x00000001c5ec10>"